# Using closure, alias and namespace extension patterns: How to allow for independent instantiations of plugin?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Simplified working [demo code here](http://jsbin.com/efeyuw/1).

Relevant JS code:

```
;(function(exports) {

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Private properties:
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var _msg = '',
    _ol = document.getElementById('debug');

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Public methods:
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    exports.init = function(arg) {

        _msg = arg;

        // Add a listener to the `window.resize` event, pass `exports`/`self` as the scope:
        _addEvent(window, 'resize', _listenForChange, exports);

    };

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Private methods:
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function _addEvent(elem, type, handle, context) {

        // Attache event:
        if (elem) {

            if (elem.addEventListener) {

                // If the browser supports event listeners, use them:
                elem.addEventListener(type, function() { handle.call(context); }, false);

            } else if (elem.attachEvent) {

                // IE & Opera:
                elem.attachEvent('on' + type, function() { handle.call(context); });

            } else {

                // Otherwise, replace the current thing bound to `on[whatever]`!
                elem['on' + type] = function() { handle.call(context); };

            }

        }

    }

    function _listenForChange() {

        var li = document.createElement('li');

        li.innerHTML = String(_msg);

        _ol.appendChild(li);

        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log(_msg);

    }

    return exports; // Expose the API.

}(window.FOO = window.FOO || {}));

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

window.onload = function() {

    FOO.init('world');

    FOO.init('universe');

};
```

#### Problem with existing code:

When re-sizing the window, I only see "universe".

#### Goal:

When browser window re-sizes, I want to world "world" and "universe" output as a list item (and to the console).

I want to have the ability to instantiate `FOO` multiple times and have it work independently from any other running instances.

#### My questions:

Is there a pattern (or patterns), similar to the one(s) that I'm currently using, that will allow me to run multiple instances of `FOO` without having the last `FOO` called trump all previously called `FOO`s?

The code I posted is obviously not real world; my end goal is to allow/modify a plugin I wrote to be used without the end user having to worry if `FOO` is already being used by another script.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything and/or provide more specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one copy of `window.FOO` and `window.FOO.init`, despite its name does not create new objects. `window.FOO.init` just overwrites `_msg` that `(function(exports) {...` closed over each time it is called. `_listenForChange()` holds a reference to the closed over `_msg`. If you want it to *keep a copy of the value* at the time `init` is called then you can do like so:

```
_addEvent(window, 'resize', listenForChange2(), exports);

var listenForChange2 = function() {
    var msg = _msg; // keep own copy of the _msg
    return function() {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = String("second version " + msg);
        _ol.appendChild(li);
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

### Review of the code posted in the EDIT #1

First of all you are still confused about closures. It is important that you understand them because they are how you associate some state with a function. But explaining closures is not within the scope of Code Review. And you probably won't get any better answers than these, the accepted answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20070510000404/http://laurens.vd.oever.nl/weblog/items2005/closures/) linked from there. You can fix your bug if you understand these.

Also the answer above fixes the bug if you KEEP the parens here:

```
_addEvent(window, 'resize', listenForChange2(), exports);
```

I the [JSBIN you posted](http://jsbin.com/efeyuw/6/edit) just add the parens and It works. So I will not repeat how can you fix the answer in the new code.

Onto the review. I will go over the code top down:

```
    exports.init = function(arg) {
```

By convention `init` method of an object is used for object initialization. It is not what it does here. Better name

```
       this._msg = arg;
```

You need not keep a copy of `_msg` since it will not be used elsewhere. You prepend the name with an underscore as if to indicate it is a private member (which practice I do not recommend BTW), but then expose it as public by assigning to `this.`. You can see, in the Firebug console for example, that Foo._msg is defined.

```
    exports.listenForChange = function() {
```

You need not expose this either.

```
    var listenForChange = function() {
```

would be just as good.

```
        var msg = this._msg;
```

If you do not create a new function, copying the value does not do anything.

```
    exports.addEvent = function(elem, type, handle, context) {
```

You need not expose this either, as it will not be called like `Foo.addEvent`.

Also adding another layer of indirection solving any problem, does not apply here. 
Whenever there is something you do not understand, namely a bug, 
adding another layer exacerbates the problem. 
What does `this` refer to when the `listenForChange` function is run?

Even if you fix your bug this may introduce another one:

```
                elem['on' + type] = function() { handle.call(context); };
```

You are overwriting the onclick. Only the last handler assigned to the `onResize` will fire.

This is unnecessary:

```
    return exports; // Expose the API.
```

No one is using the returned value. 
Moreover the comment is misleading as everything you assingn to `exports.` will be exposed,
whether you return it or not.

Comment: On the `_addEvent()`, `listenForChange2()` should be just `listenForChange2`. It should not be a call, just a passing of `listenForChange2` to `_addEvent()`.

Comment: Thank you abuzittin-gillifirca and @joseph-the-dreamer, I really appreciate the pro help! I've updated my question (see "EDIT #1") to show my progress based on your feedback. If you have the spare time, I'd love to know what your thoughts are on my updated code/question.

Comment: @abuzittin-gillifirca just curious if you have any feedback on the edit to my answer? Using your suggestion, I was only able to get "world" to output on `init` and everything else was "universe". Is there a pattern, or a way, for me to use `var foo1 = New FOO(), foo2 = New FOO(); foo1.init('world'); foo2.init('universe');`? I've nevered used `New` in a plugin before... Seems like that would do what I want, but would you recommended it based on what you've seen of my code? Thanks!

Comment: @MickyHulse First of all in this http://jsbin.com/efeyuw/2 version you NEED the parentheses after listenForChange2, because the function you need is the result of calling listenForChange2 not listenForChange2 itself. Note listenForChange2 creates a new function each time it is called that is how it is possible to have different events firing. I will try review the newly posted code as soon as job permits. code cannot be posted in comments, so i will probably append it to the previous answer..

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca WOW, thank you!!!! Your latest update really helped to clarify things for me. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it! I owe you one. Have an awesome day. :)